# AngularJs array not adding duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I wrote s small bit of code that adds names to an array. The problem I am getting is that if I try add the same name more than once it will not allow me. It also will not allow me any other name after trying to add a duplicate name. Here is my Angular code

```
    app.controller('DirectoryController', function($scope){
$scope.name='';
$scope.names= [];


$scope.addName = function(){
    $scope.names.push($scope.name);
}
```

});

And here is my html

```
    <div ng-controller= "DirectoryController">
    <h3>Name:</h3><input type="text" ng-model='name'>
    <button ng-click = "addName()">Save</button>
    <hr/>
    <span ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}<br/></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your span to this:

```
<span ng-repeat="name in names track by $index">{{name}}<br/></span>
```

By default ng-repeat tracks items in the array by reference, and duplicate literals can have the same identity. The default behavior will cause errors when duplicates exist in your array, which will cause the behavior you see (It fails to add the duplicate, and then stops working completely).

You should probably see an error from ng-repeat in your console when it encounters duplicates.

Comment: Just to clarify slightly, @dustyrockpile is saying that you might actually have the duplicates in your array, but you're not seeing them in the output. Perhaps you could peek at the contents of $scope.names to make sure or stick something like {{ names | json }} into the page just to check.

Comment: Thanks @JohnMunsch, I've updated my answer to clarify.